# EventLoopScheduler Bug?

Tags: system.reactive

I think I found a bug in EventLoopScheduler. Here is a unit test which reproduces it.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Reactive.Concurrency;

namespace EventLoopSchedulerTests {
    [TestFixture]
    public class EventLoopSchedulerTests {

    [Test]
    public void TestEventLoopScheduler() {
      var scheduler = new EventLoopScheduler();
      scheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), () => { });
      Thread.Sleep(1000);
      scheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2), () => { });
      Thread.Sleep(1000*60);
    }
  }
}
```

If you run this unit test one core will run on 100% for one minute.

I looked with Reflector in the code and analysed it and I think the problem is that the ManualResetEvent is not reset if a second action is scheduled after the "current" one.

Is this a known problem? Is there a workaround? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer on the Reactive Extensions Forum.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/8705ddf1-7cd2-41a1-b1b2-47d68f895053